# Moving carousel item to a new component produces weird space

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm using vue-slick-carousel in my app. I have the following code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="banner-container">
      <div>
        <VueSlickCarousel v-bind="settings">
          <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">

            <!-- ALTERNATIVE 1 (WORKS) -->
            <div>
              <a href="abc" target="_blank">
                <img id="picture1" src="./assets/carouse-item.png" />
                <div class="position-relative">
                  <div class="banner-description">
                    <span class="banner-title">
                      <a v-bind:href="'#'" class="header-anchor">#</a>
                      TITLE<br />
                    </span>
                    <span class="banner-alternative-text">
                      <a v-bind:href="'#'" class="header-anchor">#</a>
                      DESCRIPTION<br />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>

            <!-- ALTERNATIVE 2 (DOESN'T WORK) -->
            <!-- <Child :item="item"/> -->

          </div>
        </VueSlickCarousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

There are 2 alternatives. Alternative 1 works fine:

[image]

Alternative 2 is basically the code under Alternative 2 extracted into a new component - `Child`. It produces this output:

[image]

I can't understand why just extracting the part of code into a new component changes the layout like that.
The source code of the app is available at https://github.com/marcinjahn/vue-carousel-issue.

Comment: Check if you have given the same stylings for `child `component and see if there is something to do with position `relative` or `absolute`

Comment: what does the ```child``` element look like

Comment: The different is `.slick-slide img[data-v-e4caeaf8]{display:block}` which is lost when you wrap img into component. You just add style back this should solve.

Comment: @User28 That was it! How did you find it? I experimented with that for about an hour and I didn't notice that. And, why does this actually get lost when using a separate component?

Comment: This feature is called [Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles). From [this](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/src/SliderTrack.vue#L219) component, as you can see it used `scoped` attribute that means your slot element will effect by this style but not element in your component because it's in different scope.

Comment: @User28 Thanks a lot, your answer really helped me to understand it! I'm not sure why you didn't post it as an SO answer though?